# How to get a variable from another file in gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

I am new to `grunt`.

My requirement is that I need to uglify my files based on the variable set on another file.

Let's say I have some `abc.js` file in which I have a variable `var is_uglify = true;`

I need to read the value of the variable in gruntfile and perform the build accordingly.

If variable is `true`, I need to do:

```js
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:build','uglify']);
```

otherwise

```js
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:build']);
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by:

1. Defining a [Custom Task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks) - namely `getValue` in the gist below.
2. In the `getValue` Task/Function utilize [grunt.file.read](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.read) to obtain the contents of `abc.js`.
3. Then use a regex to match the Boolean value assigned to the variable `is_uglify`.
4. Once the Boolean value for `is_uglify` is obtained then conditionally run either the registered Task named `buildA` or `buildB` using [grunt.task.run](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run)

---

**Gruntfile.js**

The following gist shows how this can be achieved:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      // ... <-- Define as necessary.
    },
    clean: {
      build: {
        //...  <-- Define as necessary.
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('getValue', 'Gets the value of a variable', function () {
    var filepath = "path/to/abc.js", // <-- Define as necessary.
      content = grunt.file.read(filepath),
      value = content.match(/(?:var is_uglify = )(true|false);/);

    if (!value) {
      grunt.fail.warn(
        '\'var is_uglify = [true|false];\' not found in: ' + filepath['yellow']
      )
    }

    if (value[1] === 'true') {
      grunt.task.run(['buildA']);
    } else {
      grunt.task.run(['buildB']);
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  grunt.registerTask('build', ["getValue"]);
  grunt.registerTask('buildA', ['clean:build','uglify']);
  grunt.registerTask('buildB', ['clean:build']);
};
```

---

**Additional Notes**

- In the following line of code the `"path/to/abc.js"` part will need to be redefined as per your directory structure. This must be the path to your file containing `var is_uglify = ...;`:

```js
     var filepath = "path/to/abc.js",
```

- An explanation to the regex pattern `/(?:var is_uglify = )(true|false);/` can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/JhOEcr/1/). It will find the first match *only* in `abc.js`.
- The `getValue` Task/Function will warn if the `is_uglify` variable is missing and the Task/function simply fails and returns early.
- After you have defined the configuration for the `uglify` and `clean:build` Task  run `$ grunt build` via your CLI.